# Mathjax not rendering TEX formulas dynamically from PHP/Ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, dynamic, mathjax

```js
var questions = {"ques_id":"1","question":"<p><span class=\\\"math-tex\\\">\\\\(x = {-b \\\\pm \\\\sqrt{b^2-4ac} \\\\over 2a}\\\\)<\/span>&nbsp; &nbsp;Test Question new with mathjax<\/p>","ques_type":"text_based_questions","correctAnswer":3,"choices":[{"option_id":"1","value":"Option A"},{"option_id":"2","value":"Option B"},{"option_id":"3","value":"Option C"},{"option_id":"4","value":"OPtion D"}]};

$('#test-question').html(questions.question);
MathJax.Hub.Queue(["Typeset",MathJax.Hub, 'test-question']);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <script type="text/x-mathjax-config">
      MathJax.Hub.Config({
        showProcessingMessages: false,
        tex2jax: { inlineMath: [['$','$'],['\\(','\\)']] }
      });
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjax/2.7.1/MathJax.js?config=TeX-MML-AM_HTMLorMML">
    </script>
    </head>
 <body>
    <h5 class="border-bottom">Instructions: Read the question, work out your answer and select the best option.</h5>
    <p><span class="math-tex">\( \left( \sum_{k=1}^n a_k b_k \right)^2 \leq \left( \sum_{k=1}^n a_k^2 \right) \left( \sum_{k=1}^n b_k^2 \right) \)</span></p>
  <div class="question" id="test-question"></div>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

I'm getting the following question from Ajax request

MathJax is configured properly but the question coming from the JSON is not rendered by MathJax. The question are saved in MySQL database and are fetched by ajax request.

I tried everything but it still not working. Please help

Comment: You might want to create a live example using the snippets functionality. It's most likely a simple synchronization problem but there's not enough information.

Comment: @PeterKrautzberger I have added a code snippet where the MathJax coming fom the JSON is not rendered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From Json it added double slash. Plz remove that it will solve your problem.

Comment: `question = question.replace(/\\\\/g, '\\');
    question = question.replace('<span class=\\\"math-tex\\\">', '<span class=\"math-tex\">');`